Is it possible to open ArcGIS raster dataset or mosaic dataset in QGIS?
At my organisation I have a lot of mosaic datasets with ortophotomaps stored in an Oracle database (sde) but as an Esri raster format - not an Oracle GeoRaster. It works fine in ArcGIS Pro but I can't see them in QGIS.
I've done some research but maybe some answers are outdated and something has changed. Some answers suggest exporting rasters to GTiff files and then opening them in QGIS (here and here). But I don't want to double data stored on disk by exporting rasters from the database to GTiff files and adding them to QGIS as it is important to store them as the main repository in one place.
As far as I know QGIS in the past didn't support SINGLE rasters stored in a gdb or a sde database but now it's possible. What about rasters stored in a RASTER DATASET or MOSAIC DATASET?
Here's how it looks like. For an example I've created (both in file gdb and sde database) raster dataset and mosaic dataset and one file gdb with rasters stored just as single rasters.

After creating these datasets I've loaded rasters from my disk. Inside ArcGIS Pro data looks like this and shows on the map without any problems. But insinde QGIS I can see only polygon and table layers for raster and mosaic datasets and single rasters. At least single raster opens fine when stored inside file gdb.

So, is there any possibility to open raster and mosaic datasets in QGIS or is it still a proprietary format and can't be correctly loaded to QGIS?
